# I can't able to show my list results in my app (nodejs, ejs, express)

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Here is the source code link https://github.com/roshantak44/mytodolist?

Comment: What's the question?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the middleware you are using everytime you make a request you reinitialize the todolist as an empty array you should do this

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
if (typeof(req.session.todolist) == 'undefined') {
    var list = req.session.todolist || [];
}
next();
})
```

then in the get request

```
res.render('todo.ejs', {todolist: list});
```

in the post

```
    list.push(req.body.newtodo)
```

and in the delete request

```
  list.splice(req.params.id, 1);
```